# Download an image through URL

Tags: java, url, network-programming, download

I am trying to download the high resolution product image, on this link

http://www.hookerfurniture.com/index.cfm/furniture/furniture-catalog.show-product/American-furniture/3005-75310/spindle-back-side-chair---ebony.cfm

when click on the **Download a Hi-Resolution Photo**, the i can download it easily, but when i try to copy the image URL, and then download it from a different tab i got the 3005_75310.jpg Does not exist.

So i tried to see the request headers from the first request and set them in my URL java object, but the created file is empty, does anyone have an idea?

```
public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) {
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(imageUrl);
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();

        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset",
                "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");

        uc.setRequestProperty(
                "Referer",
                "http://www.hookerfurniture.com/index.cfm/furniture/furniture-catalog.show-product/American-furniture/3005-75310/spindle-back-side-chair---ebony.cfm");

        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: What HTTP status code is returned by your request?

Comment: Try a more accurate referrer such as the link already posted.

Comment: when I copy the URL (http://www.hookerfurniture.com/index.cfm/furniture/furniture-catalog.photo-download/photo/3005_75310.jpg) into a new tab, 200 OK, but 3005_75310.jpg Does not exist. Please Visit Hookerfurniture.com for Product Information. so what is happening here?  But when clicked from within their website, the download start fine

Comment: that is the main product page http://www.hookerfurniture.com/index.cfm/furniture/furniture-catalog.show-product/American-furniture/3005-75310/spindle-back-side-chair---ebony.cfm

Comment: You go to a lot of trouble to set up your UrlConnection, then you use url.openStream() and not uc.getInputStream()....

Answer (score 0):

The provided referrer is not what the website coder is expecting as a method to prevent the scraping you are performing.  Example working request:

```
$ wget \
  --referer=http://www.hookerfurniture.com/index.cfm/furniture/furniture-catalog.show-product/American-furniture/3005-75310/spindle-back-side-chair---ebony.cfm \
  http://www.hookerfurniture.com/index.cfm/furniture/furniture-catalog.photo-download/photo/3005_75310.jpg


Length: unspecified [image/jpeg]
Saving to: `3005_75310.jpg'

    [  <=>                                                                                ] 346,125      949K/s   in 0.4s

2013-01-29 13:24:02 (949 KB/s) - `3005_75310.jpg' saved [346125]
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, it looks like the only vital header is the "Referer" header:

This fails:

```
curl "http://www.hookerfurniture.com/index.cfm/furniture/furniture-catalog.photo-download/photo/3005_75310.jpg" > /test/3005_75310.jpg
```

This works:

```
curl -H "Referer: http://www.hookerfurniture.com/index.cfm/furniture/furniture-catalog.show-product/American-furniture/3005-75310/spindle-back-side-chair---ebony.cfm" "http://www.hookerfurniture.com/index.cfm/furniture/furniture-catalog.photo-download/photo/3005_75310.jpg" > /test/3005_75310.jpg
```

For pulling image data in Java, I've found most success using a DataInputStream's readFully() method.